# How to populate a dropdown list from array in FORM API

Tags: forms, theming

Hopefully this is clearer, and my last question in a long time!

Using PDO I have connected to an external DB, I can query this and return an array of values, Using html/php I can populate a standard select box. However I am unsure how to do this in the Form API, taking the array from the second paragraph, or do I query within the form item that produces the drop down? I want to take the name and the id, display the name. So that I can store the ID later.

```
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT admin_name, adminuser_id FROM adminuser_tbl");
if ($stmt->execute()) {
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$user_list = array();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $user_list[$row->adminuser_id] = $row->admin_name;
}
}


$form['user_list']=array(
    '#type'=>'select',
    '#title' => t('Users'),
    '#options' => $user_list,
    '#multiple' => false,
    '#attributes'=>array('size'=>4),
    '#weight'=>8,
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a while looping over your result, populate array.

```
$user_list = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { // See this line in your original code
   $user_list[$row->user_id] = $row->name; 
   // Apply transformations and conditions here, if needed
}
```

Or, as Clive suggested:

```
$user_list = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

Then simply use this array

```
'#options' => $user_list,
```

---

By the way, if you really want to make assignment in condition, proper way to write it is:

```
while ( ($row = $stmt->fetch()) )
```

As you can see, assignment is wrapped in double parentheses. It is the way to say future developers and code review tools "yes, it is not a typo, I really wanted it this way, I did not forgot about second `=`".

Comment: Or even quicker: `$user_list = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);` (would mean the query parameters need to be reversed to `user_id, name`)

Comment: @Clive I usually make some operations in the loop, too. And Drupal's DB api don't have PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR as far as I remember... So I just forgot, my mistake.

Comment: We have [`fetchAllKeyed()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3AfetchAllKeyed/7) which is functionality equivalent :)

Comment: @Clive Good to know. I'm yet to encounter a situation where I will not need a loop anyway ;) If I will, I hope I'll remember this.

Comment: @Clive I have edited the question, with what I have tried, I'm getting a blank box? I'm obviously doing something wrong? the array $user_list is empty

Comment: @Tom `dpr($user_list)` and  `dpr($row)` after each iteration (well, cut it to about 5 database rows for testing) and we might be able to tell something. Also - are you sure your watchdog does not report connection errors?

Comment: @Mołot I edited the question, I was missing the PDO fetch.